# How to get multiple values for multiple keys from Hashmap in a single operation?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

I want to get values for more than one key using `HashMap`, for example:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(1, "Hello");
map.put(2, "World");
map.put(3, "New");
map.put(4, "Old");
```

Now I want to combine values for `1` and `2` and create a `List<String>` output.
I can do this with 2 times get an operation or create one function that takes a key list and return a list of values.

But is there any in-built *util* function that do the same job?

Comment: *I can do this with 2 times get an operation or **create one function that takes a key list and return a list of values.*** ... Isn't that the same to what the marked answer does? What were you actually looking for?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html)s:

```
List<Integer> keys = List.of(1,2);
List<String> values = 
    keys.stream()
        .map(map::get)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull) // get rid of null values
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will result in the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html):

```
[Hello, World]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can take an input [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) having the keys to query for and use stream operations [`Stream#filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) and [`Stream#map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) to filter and map the results and finally collect the values into a list:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(1, "Hello");
map.put(2, "World");
map.put(3, "New");
map.put(4, "Old");

Set<Integer> keys = Set.of(1, 2);

List<String> values = map.entrySet()
                         .stream()
                         .filter(ent -> keys.contains(ent.getKey()))
                         .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(values);
```

Output:

```
[Hello, World]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IntStream.of(1, 2)
        .map(map::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I would suggest to check null, as eran did.